# Ativar autenticação Nginx para um URL específica

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, htpasswd

Estou trabalhando com um painel de controle e preciso colocar uma autenticação no acesso à pasta do admin.

Já criei o usuário e senha, a configuração do nginx esta dessa forma:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name localhost;
root /usr/local/pannel/www;

gzip on;
gzip_http_version  1.1;
gzip_comp_level    5;
gzip_min_length    256;
gzip_proxied       any;
gzip_vary          on;

gzip_types
  application/atom+xml
  application/javascript
  application/json
  application/rss+xml
  application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  application/x-font-ttf
  application/x-web-app-manifest+json
  application/xhtml+xml
  application/xml
  font/opentype
  image/svg+xml
  image/x-icon
  text/css
  text/plain
  text/x-component;

ssl_certificate     /usr/local/svmstack/nginx/ssl/ssl.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/svmstack/nginx/ssl/ssl.key;
ssl_session_timeout 6m;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

index index.php;

include services/custom/legacy-master-before-php-location-443.conf;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include services/custom/legacy-master-inside-php-location-443.conf;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/svmstack/fpm/socket/web.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
include services/custom/legacy-master-after-php-location-443.conf;
}
```

Eu poderia simplesmente adicionar o código abaixo dentro de `location`, no entanto, nesse caso, ele solicitaria autenticação para todos os arquivos no diretório **/usr/local/pannel/www**;.

```
auth_basic "Restricted";
auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/pannel/htpasswd;
```

Como posso criar um novo `location`, dentro dessa mesma chave `server`, para uma URL específica, que no caso seria: /usr/local/pannel/www/admin/login.php

Eu preciso de autenticação somente quando este arquivo é acessado (login.php).

Tentei fazer dessa forma mas não funcionou:

```
location /admincp {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/pannel/htpasswd;
}
```

Comment: Removi, temporariamente, minha resposta. Tenta dessa forma: https://pastebin.com/raw/N10BPTV7 (No link há dois links para teste)

Comment: Não consegui acessar o link: This page has been removed!

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Y3szYSUQ

Comment: Testei, fez download também.

Comment: Se você remover o `location` da linha 12 a 15 (Baseado no exemplo acima), funciona?

Comment: Sim, ele acessa mas não solicita os dados para autenticação.

Comment: @ValdeirPsr Consegui resolver, era preciso informar o nginx que o arquivo era acessível, fiz isso repetindo as regras do fastcgi, ficou assim: https://pastebin.com/9DcHy4EM

Comment: Se quiser postar a solução, em seguida marco como resolvida.

Comment: que bom que conseguiu. Pode colocá-la como resposta, mérito seu. ^^

Comment: Na verdade eu não sei se posso responder a minha própria pergunta rs, não cheguei a ler os termos do site.

Comment: pode responder sim. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422/responder-sua-pr%C3%B3pria-pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui achar a solução com um amigo meu, ficou dessa forma:

```
location ~ /admin/login.php {
    include services/custom/legacy-master-inside-php-location-443.conf;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/svmstack/fpm/socket/web.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /usr/local/pannel/htpasswd;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include services/custom/legacy-master-inside-php-location-443.conf;
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/usr/local/svmstack/fpm/socket/web.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi.conf;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS $https;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```